# How to add checkboxes to a list using javascript

Tags: javascript, list, checkbox, append

i am having problems adding checkboxes to my list as it is generated. i want to be able to check or uncheck items that are added using the addToList function.

I have tried playing around with the html, and making a function in the javascript, but still no success.

`````
function addToList(){
  let food = document.getElementById("food").value;
  let amount = document.getElementById("amount").value;
  let unit = document.getElementById("unit").value;

  let li = document.createElement("li");
  li.textContent = food + ' ' + amount + ' ' + unit + '.';
  document.getElementById("foodlist").appendChild(li);
};


function addToPantry () {
  for (i = 0; i<foodlist.length; i++){
    let name = foodlist[0];
    pantry.push(`${name}: [${amount}, [${unit}]]`)
  }


````
HTML
````

<input type="text" name="" value="food" id="food">
  <br><br>

<input type="text" name="" value="amount" id="amount">
  <br><br>

<select id="unit">
  <option value="oz">ounces</option>
  <option value="lb">pounds</option>
  <option value="servings">servings</option>
</select>
  <br><br>

<button  onclick ="addToList(), addToPantry()" type="button" name="button" id="addButton">add</button>

<ul id="foodlist"></ul>
`````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function addToList() {
  let food = document.getElementById("food").value;
  let amount = document.getElementById("amount").value;
  let unit = document.getElementById("unit").value;

  let input = document.createElement('input');
  input.type = "checkbox";
  input.addEventListener('change', deleteTodo);

  let li = document.createElement("li");
  li.textContent = food + ' ' + amount + ' ' + unit + '.';
  li.appendChild(input);
  document.getElementById("foodlist").appendChild(li);
};


function addToPantry() {
  for (i = 0; i < foodlist.length; i++) {
    let name = foodlist[0];
    pantry.push(`${name}: [${amount}, [${unit}]]`)
  }
}

function deleteTodo(e) {
  e.currentTarget.parentNode.remove(e);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="" value="food" id="food">
<input type="text" name="" value="amount" id="amount">


<select id="unit">
  <option value="oz">ounces</option>
  <option value="lb">pounds</option>
  <option value="servings">servings</option>
</select>

<button onclick="addToList(), addToPantry()" type="button" name="button" id="addButton">add</button>

<ul id="foodlist"></ul>
```